# concatenate all columns from with names of columns also in it, one string for every row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

```
CREATE TABLE myTable 
(
    COL1 int, 
    COL2 varchar(10), 
    COL3 float
)

INSERT INTO myTable
VALUES (1, 'c2r1', NULL), (2, 'c2r2', 2.335)
```

I want an output with for every row of a table one string with all columns and the names in it.

Something like:

```
COL1=1|COL2=c2r1|COL3=NULL
COL1=2|COL2=c2r2|COL3=2.3335
```

I have a table with lot of columns so it has to be dynamic (it would use it on different tables also), is there an easy solution where I can do it and choose separator and things like that... (It has to deal with NULL-values & numeric values also.)

I am using SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Why in the world would you want output like this? It violates everything about databases.

Comment: How about dates? And datetime values? You're going to have to show all of the potential edge cases if you want a reliable answer that isn't going to take 40 iterations to catch them all. (But honestly you should do this in a client application language, not T-SQL.)

Comment: What is the use-case for this? What is going to consume this single concatenated string?

Comment: I have data from different tables (artificial intelligence models, models change now and then) that I want to save at the moment that I use that particular row.
But afterwards the data can change a bit & I want an easy & simple way to store the data so that I can check if necessary the stored row with the latest version.
I don't want a perfect database, I want a simple solution. I don't care about violation database rules.

Comment: What is the expected result when `COL2` is `'#|COL42=||'` or `'NULL'`? You might want to look into using [XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of pipe-delimited confusion.

Comment: @HABO, I don't get an error if I change COL2 in what you propose, so that's fine. 
(And '#|COL42=||' is not a likely result in my table.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are on 2019, string_agg() with a bit if JSON

**Example**

```
 Select NewVal
  From  MyTable A
  Cross Apply ( Select NewVal = string_agg([key]+'='+isnull(value,'null'),'|')
                 From OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES  )) 
             ) B
```

**Results**

```
NewVal
COL1=1|COL2=c2r1|COL3=null
COL1=2|COL2=c2r2|COL3=2.335000000000000e+000   -- Don't like the float
```

**EDIT to Trap FLOATs**

```
Select NewVal
  From  MyTable A
  Cross Apply ( Select NewVal = string_agg([key]+'='+isnull(case when value like '%0e+0%' then concat('',convert(decimal(15,3),convert(float,value))) else value end,'null'),'|')
                 From OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES  )) 
             ) B
```

**Results**

```
NewVal
COL1=1|COL2=c2r1|COL3=null
COL1=2|COL2=c2r2|COL3=2.335
```

Comment: Almost exactly what I want, thank you!
Only the floating points are a bit of a problem, because I have a lot of them, so I will have a look if I can do something about it. But the rest is perfect, f.e. dates are parsed very well, NULL,...

Comment: @gilberke You can embed a case where value like '%0e+0%' and convert to a decimal

Comment: @gilberke See EDIT to trap FLOATs

Comment: I changed '%0e+0%' to '%e[-+]0%'  to find + & - after the e, and I deleted the first 0 to find all floating values in the string. Thank you, now it works like I want it.
(A database in compatibility_level on a sql server 2019 gives an error, that was something that I faced.)

Comment: @gilberke WELL DONE!

Answer (score 1):

Would one dare to abuse json for this?

```
SELECT REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (ca.js,'":','='), ',"','|'), '"',''), '[{','') ,'}]','') AS data
FROM (SELECT col1 as id FROM myTable) AS list
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT t.col1
  , t.col2
  , cast(t.col3 as decimal(16,3)) as col3
  FROM myTable t
  WHERE t.col1 = list.id
  FOR JSON AUTO, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
) ca(js)
```

It'll work with a simple `SELECT t.*` in the cross apply.
But the floats tend to be bit too long then.